# Switching to iFrame using phantoms and protractor

Tags: angularjs, selenium, phantomjs, protractor, e2e-testing

I am trying to switch to iframe using protractor with phantomjs. The switchTo.frameById does not seem to work. Any leads on how to get this working would be of great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this code:

```
browser.switchTo().frame('iframe-name');
```

When iFrame name is:

```
<iframe name="iframe-name" ng-src="{{someSrc}}"></iframe>
```

It is working for me

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works great. Another weird problem am facing now is that inside iframe in phantoms my scripts are getting timed out as cannot find the paths. The same paths works in other browsers though!

Comment: Is it possible you have relative urls / cross domain issues? Can you share code example? If my answer was correct and answered your question I would love if you mark it as "accept answer" (:

Comment: also if you need to get out of the iframe you can use 

browser.driver.switchTo().defaultContent();

Comment: Post doing switch to iframe i am doing a  driver.findElement(by.xpath(xpath)) and then a getText() on it.  I read somewhere that phantoms cannot perform any action inside iframe but can only do read operation. Anything to do with versions? i am using protractor 2.1.0, phantomjs 2.0.0 and selenium 2.42 standalone